# How to solve $x'=\frac{1-x-t}{x+t}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I would be greatful if you help me to find the solutions of this differential equation:

$[E]: x'=\frac{1-x-t}{x+t}$.

The exercise gives a hint: use $u=ax+bt+c$. I am trying with $u=x+t$ and $u=1-x-t$ but I can't isolate $u$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x' =\frac{1-x-t}{x+t} = \frac{1}{x+t} - 1 \implies x'+1 = \frac{1}{x+t}$$

Let $x+t = u  \implies x'+1 = u'$

So, $$u' = \frac{1}{u}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x+t$, then $u'=x'+1$ or $x'=u'-1$, thus the DE becomes
$$u'-1=\frac{1-u}{u}$$
or
$$u'=\frac{1}{u}$$
i.e. $$\frac{1}{2}u^2=t+c\\
\implies (x+t)^2=2t+2c
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x'=\frac{1-x-t}{x+t}$$

$$x'+1=\frac{1-x-t}{x+t}+1$$
$$(x+t)'=\frac{1-x-t}{x+t}+1$$
$$(x+t)'=\frac{1}{x+t}$$
This is  a separable DE.
$$(x+t)d(x+t)=dt$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1-(x+t)}{x+t} $$
Let $$k = x+t$$
Then $$ \frac{dx}{dt} + 1 = \frac{dk}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} =  \frac{dk}{dt} -1 $$and$$ \frac{dk}{dt} - 1 = \frac{1-k}{k}  $$
$$ \frac{dk}{dt} = \frac{1-k}{k} + 1 = \frac{1}{k}$$
$$\int k\ dk = \int dt $$
$$\frac{k^2}{2} + c = t$$
substituting $k$ with $x+t$
$$\frac{(x+t)^2}{2} + c = t$$